# Python Virtual Environment - PHP Exec Command does not work

Tags: php, python, ubuntu, virtualenv, exec

I have to call python from PHP in Ubuntu. I do that this way:

```
$command = 'usr/bin/python3.6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/python/test.py';
exec($command, $output, $r);
```

However when I create a virtual environment and do the same the command does not work at all:

```
$command = '/root/venv/bin/python3.6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/python/test.py';
exec($command, $output, $r);
```

Venv and original python are the same. The python file  test.py chmod-ed to 777.

When I execute:

```
/root/venv/bin/python3.6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/python/test.py
```

from command like (terminal) - it works without any problem. So i guess this has something to do with activating the Environment.

What do you think the problem could be?

Or how can I debug it, not sure where can I find the log files for python. I do not see any error for php.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use for both crontabs and calling a .py file via PHP shell_exce() or exec().  I'm not expert, but I fumble around long enough to get things to work.

```
$exec_str = "cd /home/dockethound/public_html/layout/pydocx && /home/flohosting/PythonTest/PythonTest/bin/python create-docx.py \"".$GET['email']."\" \"".$GET['doc_id']."\" >2&1";
exec($exec_str);
```

I'm using a GoDaddy VPS with some Python modules installed (python-docx).

My understanding of the command is that it cd to the directory where the script is (even though I'm then calling it from the absolute path on the server, which seems unneccessary), and then calling my `virtualenv` for python3.6.  I installed it in PythonTest and it's working so I never changed it.

Oh, the && was very important.  I had that in the crontab but not in my shell_exec() command and it wasn't working.  I checked my crontab again, saw that there and added it and BOOM, my shell_exec() / exec() started working.

Hope this helps

PS - The variables at the end are passing arguments (or parameters) into the script.  I use the following to access them:

```
import sys
#declare the variable
var_1 = sys.argv[1]
var_2 = sys.argv[2]
```

argv[0] is always the first part of the script, i.e., from `cd` to the name of the script.